# jQuery-ui sortable() not working with jQuery onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery .load function to import my page into index.html.

**So this is my index.html:**

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>

    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>


        <div id="content"></div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    <script>


        $(function() {

            $('#content').load('mycontent.html');

            $( ".row" ).sortable();
            $( ".row" ).disableSelection();         

        });     

    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

**and this is my other page that I'm including:**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">Sortable Div</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Sortable Div</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Sortable Div</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The problem is that when the included code is part of the index.html the sortable code works BUT when I use .load to include the html into the page it doesn't.

Why..and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
$('#content').load('mycontent.html', function () {
   $( ".row" ).sortable();
   $( ".row" ).disableSelection(); 
});
```

The problem with your solution is that `.row` is not present when you load the page so sortable can't registred to that class.